# Problems with ligatures

Tags: tex4ht, ligatures, tex4ebook

I have some problems to make ligatures (not) work in epub.

my MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
the field of ff is flight.
fioriture flashent difficilement
\end{document}
```

[image: Problems with null utf8]

Comment: my conf file is
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local my_filter = filter{"cleanspan", "fixligatures"}
Make:htlatex()
Make:match("html$",my_filter)

logs:
herve@debianForEpub:~$ tex4ebook -c conf2.cfg -f epub  mwe.tex
Output dir: 
Compiler:       latex
Latex options:   -jobname=mwe 
tex4ht.sty :    conf2.cfg,
tex4ht
build_file      mwe.mk4
mwe-epub/OEBPS
mwe-epub/mimetype
Using build file        mwe.mk4
setting param correct_exit
latex mwe "conf2.cfg,,charset=utf-8,epub" " -cmozhtf -utf8" "" " -jobname=mwe "
Output file: mwe.epub
Make4ht run

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add your conf file to the question? And also the output as code, rather than image?

Comment: the conf file est minimal
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble


the result :
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,charset=utf-8,epub,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="mwe.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mwe.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
<!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" >the

Comment: nothing copy because of the null char in utf8

I am working on this for 2 days.

Comment: this seems like wrong font support file for Libertine. which TeX distribution do you use? It works for me on TL 2018.

Comment: debian strech  TL 2016.20170123-5
i wiil test on a debian SID - TL 2018.20180824-1: all

Comment: TL 2016 is really old, you should try the newer version

Comment: i'am installind new debian wm with 2108.201808

Comment: on fresh install i get 
<!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" >the ffeld of fl is ffiight. fforiture ffiashent dificilement « pour exemple » il
faut monter
</p>
so    fi -> ff ff ->fl fl->ffi

it breaks if there is a fnt packages load after  fontenc and inputenc

Comment: ah, I can see that now. it seems that LIbertine uses slightly non-standard font encoding and they swapped positions for ligatures. I will try to fix the font config files later

Comment: quand or cette works for me. doesn't this problem show when you use bold or italic font?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Libertine font uses slightly modified version of the `T1` font encoding, so positions of some ligatures are moved. It is necessary to provide tex4ht font configuration files for all variants of Libertine font. As there are 1288 files in the Libertine font directory, I will provide it only for possible variants used in your TeX file.

There are two types of font configuration files. First type defines Unicode characters mapped to characters used in the font. The second type references the font table saved in the first type and add some CSS definitions for font style. For example bold and italic fonts should have the same characters as the regular font, so it is possible to reference the regular font to save some space.

The font table, `LinLibertineT-tlf-t1.htf`:

```
LinLibertineT-tlf-t1 0 255
'&#x0060;'  ''  grave
'&#x00B4;'  ''  acute
'&#x02C6;'  ''  circumflex
'&#x02DC;'  ''  tilde
'&#x00A8;'  ''  dieresis
'&#x02DD;'  ''  hungarumlaut
'&#x02DA;'  ''  ring
'&#x02C7;'  ''  caron
'&#x02D8;'  ''  breve
'&#x00AF;'  ''  macron
'&#x02D9;'  ''  dotaccent
'&#x00B8;'  ''  cedilla
'&#x02DB;'  ''  ogonek
'&#x201A;'  ''  quotesinglbase
'&#x2039;'  ''  guilsinglleft
'&#x203A;'  ''  guilsinglright
'&#x201C;'  ''  quotedblleft
'&#x201D;'  ''  quotedblright
'&#x201E;'  ''  quotedblbase
'&#x00AB;'  ''  guillemotleft
'&#x00BB;'  ''  guillemotright
'&#x2013;'  ''  endash
'&#x2014;'  ''  emdash
'&#xnil;'   ''  .notdef
'&#x2080;'  ''  perthousandzero
'&#x0131;'  ''  dotlessi
'&#x0237;'  ''  dotlessj
'&#xFB01;'  ''  f_i
'&#xFB03;'  ''  f_f_i
'&#xFB00;'  ''  f_f
'&#xFB02;'  ''  f_l
'&#xFB04;'  ''  f_f_l
'&#x2423;'  ''  uni2423
'&#x0021;'  ''  exclam
'&#x0022;'  ''  quotedbl
'&#x0023;'  ''  numbersign
'&#x0024;'  ''  dollar
'&#x0025;'  ''  percent
'&#x0026;'  ''  ampersand
'&#x2019;'  ''  quoteright
'&#x0028;'  ''  parenleft
'&#x0029;'  ''  parenright
'&#x002A;'  ''  asterisk
'&#x002B;'  ''  plus
'&#x002C;'  ''  comma
'&#x002D;'  ''  hyphen
'&#x002E;'  ''  period
'&#x002F;'  ''  slash
'&#x0030;'  ''  zero
'&#x0031;'  ''  one
'&#x0032;'  ''  two
'&#x0033;'  ''  three
'&#x0034;'  ''  four
'&#x0035;'  ''  five
'&#x0036;'  ''  six
'&#x0037;'  ''  seven
'&#x0038;'  ''  eight
'&#x0039;'  ''  nine
'&#x003A;'  ''  colon
'&#x003B;'  ''  semicolon
'&#x003C;'  ''  less
'&#x003D;'  ''  equal
'&#x003E;'  ''  greater
'&#x003F;'  ''  question
'&#x0040;'  ''  at
'&#x0041;'  ''  A
'&#x0042;'  ''  B
'&#x0043;'  ''  C
'&#x0044;'  ''  D
'&#x0045;'  ''  E
'&#x0046;'  ''  F
'&#x0047;'  ''  G
'&#x0048;'  ''  H
'&#x0049;'  ''  I
'&#x004A;'  ''  J
'&#x004B;'  ''  K
'&#x004C;'  ''  L
'&#x004D;'  ''  M
'&#x004E;'  ''  N
'&#x004F;'  ''  O
'&#x0050;'  ''  P
'&#x0051;'  ''  Q
'&#x0052;'  ''  R
'&#x0053;'  ''  S
'&#x0054;'  ''  T
'&#x0055;'  ''  U
'&#x0056;'  ''  V
'&#x0057;'  ''  W
'&#x0058;'  ''  X
'&#x0059;'  ''  Y
'&#x005A;'  ''  Z
'&#x005B;'  ''  bracketleft
'&#x005C;'  ''  backslash
'&#x005D;'  ''  bracketright
'&#x005E;'  ''  asciicircum
'&#x005F;'  ''  underscore
'&#x2018;'  ''  quoteleft
'&#x0061;'  ''  a
'&#x0062;'  ''  b
'&#x0063;'  ''  c
'&#x0064;'  ''  d
'&#x0065;'  ''  e
'&#x0066;'  ''  f
'&#x0067;'  ''  g
'&#x0068;'  ''  h
'&#x0069;'  ''  i
'&#x006A;'  ''  j
'&#x006B;'  ''  k
'&#x006C;'  ''  l
'&#x006D;'  ''  m
'&#x006E;'  ''  n
'&#x006F;'  ''  o
'&#x0070;'  ''  p
'&#x0071;'  ''  q
'&#x0072;'  ''  r
'&#x0073;'  ''  s
'&#x0074;'  ''  t
'&#x0075;'  ''  u
'&#x0076;'  ''  v
'&#x0077;'  ''  w
'&#x0078;'  ''  x
'&#x0079;'  ''  y
'&#x007A;'  ''  z
'&#x007B;'  ''  braceleft
'&#x007C;'  ''  bar
'&#x007D;'  ''  braceright
'&#x007E;'  ''  asciitilde
'&#x002D;'  ''  hyphen
'&#x0102;'  ''  Abreve
'&#x0104;'  ''  Aogonek
'&#x0106;'  ''  Cacute
'&#x010C;'  ''  Ccaron
'&#x010E;'  ''  Dcaron
'&#x011A;'  ''  Ecaron
'&#x0118;'  ''  Eogonek
'&#x011E;'  ''  Gbreve
'&#x0139;'  ''  Lacute
'&#x013D;'  ''  Lcaron
'&#x0141;'  ''  Lslash
'&#x0143;'  ''  Nacute
'&#x0147;'  ''  Ncaron
'&#x014A;'  ''  Eng
'&#x0150;'  ''  Ohungarumlaut
'&#x0154;'  ''  Racute
'&#x0158;'  ''  Rcaron
'&#x015A;'  ''  Sacute
'&#x0160;'  ''  Scaron
'&#x015E;'  ''  Scedilla
'&#x0164;'  ''  Tcaron
'&#x0162;'  ''  Tcedilla
'&#x0170;'  ''  Uhungarumlaut
'&#x016E;'  ''  Uring
'&#x0178;'  ''  Ydieresis
'&#x0179;'  ''  Zacute
'&#x017D;'  ''  Zcaron
'&#x017B;'  ''  Zdotaccent
'&#x0132;'  ''  IJ
'&#x0130;'  ''  Idotaccent
'&#x0111;'  ''  dcroat
'&#x00A7;'  ''  section
'&#x0103;'  ''  abreve
'&#x0105;'  ''  aogonek
'&#x0107;'  ''  cacute
'&#x010D;'  ''  ccaron
'&#x010F;'  ''  dcaron
'&#x011B;'  ''  ecaron
'&#x0119;'  ''  eogonek
'&#x011F;'  ''  gbreve
'&#x013A;'  ''  lacute
'&#x013E;'  ''  lcaron
'&#x0142;'  ''  lslash
'&#x0144;'  ''  nacute
'&#x0148;'  ''  ncaron
'&#x014B;'  ''  eng
'&#x0151;'  ''  ohungarumlaut
'&#x0155;'  ''  racute
'&#x0159;'  ''  rcaron
'&#x015B;'  ''  sacute
'&#x0161;'  ''  scaron
'&#x015F;'  ''  scedilla
'&#x0165;'  ''  tcaron
'&#x0163;'  ''  tcedilla
'&#x0171;'  ''  uhungarumlaut
'&#x016F;'  ''  uring
'&#x00FF;'  ''  ydieresis
'&#x017A;'  ''  zacute
'&#x017E;'  ''  zcaron
'&#x017C;'  ''  zdotaccent
'&#x0133;'  ''  ij
'&#x00A1;'  ''  exclamdown
'&#x00BF;'  ''  questiondown
'&#x00A3;'  ''  sterling
'&#x00C0;'  ''  Agrave
'&#x00C1;'  ''  Aacute
'&#x00C2;'  ''  Acircumflex
'&#x00C3;'  ''  Atilde
'&#x00C4;'  ''  Adieresis
'&#x00C5;'  ''  Aring
'&#x00C6;'  ''  AE
'&#x00C7;'  ''  Ccedilla
'&#x00C8;'  ''  Egrave
'&#x00C9;'  ''  Eacute
'&#x00CA;'  ''  Ecircumflex
'&#x00CB;'  ''  Edieresis
'&#x00CC;'  ''  Igrave
'&#x00CD;'  ''  Iacute
'&#x00CE;'  ''  Icircumflex
'&#x00CF;'  ''  Idieresis
'&#x00D0;'  ''  Eth
'&#x00D1;'  ''  Ntilde
'&#x00D2;'  ''  Ograve
'&#x00D3;'  ''  Oacute
'&#x00D4;'  ''  Ocircumflex
'&#x00D5;'  ''  Otilde
'&#x00D6;'  ''  Odieresis
'&#x0152;'  ''  OE
'&#x00D8;'  ''  Oslash
'&#x00D9;'  ''  Ugrave
'&#x00DA;'  ''  Uacute
'&#x00DB;'  ''  Ucircumflex
'&#x00DC;'  ''  Udieresis
'&#x00DD;'  ''  Yacute
'&#x00DE;'  ''  Thorn
'&#xnil;'   ''  .notdef
'&#x00E0;'  ''  agrave
'&#x00E1;'  ''  aacute
'&#x00E2;'  ''  acircumflex
'&#x00E3;'  ''  atilde
'&#x00E4;'  ''  adieresis
'&#x00E5;'  ''  aring
'&#x00E6;'  ''  ae
'&#x00E7;'  ''  ccedilla
'&#x00E8;'  ''  egrave
'&#x00E9;'  ''  eacute
'&#x00EA;'  ''  ecircumflex
'&#x00EB;'  ''  edieresis
'&#x00EC;'  ''  igrave
'&#x00ED;'  ''  iacute
'&#x00EE;'  ''  icircumflex
'&#x00EF;'  ''  idieresis
'&#x00F0;'  ''  eth
'&#x00F1;'  ''  ntilde
'&#x00F2;'  ''  ograve
'&#x00F3;'  ''  oacute
'&#x00F4;'  ''  ocircumflex
'&#x00F5;'  ''  otilde
'&#x00F6;'  ''  odieresis
'&#x0153;'  ''  oe
'&#x00F8;'  ''  oslash
'&#x00F9;'  ''  ugrave
'&#x00FA;'  ''  uacute
'&#x00FB;'  ''  ucircumflex
'&#x00FC;'  ''  udieresis
'&#x00FD;'  ''  yacute
'&#x00FE;'  ''  thorn
'&#x00DF;'  ''  germandbls
LinLibertineT-tlf-t1 0 255
```

file LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1.htf:

```
.LinLibertineT-tlf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineTB-tlf-t1  font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

font LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1.htf

```
.LinLibertineT-tlf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineTI-tlf-t1  font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

file LinLibertineTBI-tlf-t1.htf:

```
.LinLibertineT-tlf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineTBI-tlf-t1  font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

file LinLibertineT-tlf-sc-t1:

```
.LinLibertineT-tlf-t1
htfcss:  LinLibertineT-tlf-sc-t1  font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: small-caps; font-family: "Linux Libertine O",serif;
```

Save these files in the directory with yout TeX file. It is also necessary to request Linux Libertine as the main text font, using this configuration:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{body{font-family: "Linux Libertine O", serif;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Sample:

[image]