# Problems with ligature and libertine font -

Tags: tex4ht, ligatures, libertine, tex4ebook

I cannot post a comment under my previous question so  (i fixed some files because i misunderstood somethings, but there is a problème with tt => fl in sffamily not smallcaps and it seems it cannot do sffamily regular

why do pdflatex have thoses ligatures but they do not work in tex4ebook (lualatex ?)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newcommand{\testfont}[1]{
rmfamily\\
{\rmfamily #1\\{\scshape #1}\\\\
\textbf{#1\\{\scshape #1}}\\\\
\textit{#1\\{\scshape #1}}\\}

sffamily\\
{\sffamily #1\\{\scshape #1}\\\\
\textbf{#1\\{\scshape #1}}\\\\
\textit{#1\\{\scshape #1}}\\}
}
\begin{document}
\testfont{ff fli ffi ffr tt th qu FF FLI FFI TT TH}
\end{document}
```

tex4ebook result

[image: tex4ebook]

pdflatex result

[image]

[Problems with ligatures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451149/problems-with-ligatures)

Comment: Please clarify what the issue is. Which ligatures are missing? Do note that the Biolinum sans-serif font (which is loaded by the `libertine` package) contains fewer f-ligatures than does the Libertine serif font.

Comment: 1 -  tt becomes fl in sffamily not smallcaps
2 - there is not ssfamily medium font

The problem is that it gives wrong ligature, 'cette' => 'cfle' in sffamily

Comment: I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with `tex4ebook`, even though I'm quite familiar with LuaLaTeX. A thought: Have you tried replacing the instruction `\usepackage{libertine}` with (a) loading the `fontspec` package and (b) executing `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` and `\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O` (with suitably chosen options, as needed)?

Comment: @Mico the problem is that tex4ht (which tex4ebook uses in the background) uses special files for translation between characters in the tfm file and Unicode. They also contain information about font style, weight, name, etc. These files must be created for each font and the files for Linux Libertine contain wrong mappings between certain ligatures and the output text.

Comment: @michal.h21 - Many thanks for this explanation/clarification. To really solve the OP's issue, then, should somebody contact the maintainer(s) of the `libertine` package and/or the `Linux Libertine O` font and point out that some of the ligature mappings are wrong?

Comment: @Mico I don't think Libertine mappings are wrong, they just use some non-usual ligatures that are not present in the T1 fontenc, so wrong are `tex4ht` support files, which assume that they are in T1.

Answer (score 3):

This is result of wrong support files for Libertine fonts in tex4ht. Each used font needs special file with mapping of the character codes in the DVI file to Unicode. The mappings for fonts used in your document expects the standard T1 font encoding, but Libertine fonts use some additional ligatures, so some characters are mapped incorrectly.

The process of creation of the mapping files is quite difficult and error prone. I am working on a tool called [Htfgen](https://github.com/michal-h21/htfgen) which can in ideal cases generate the mapping files automatically. It contain lot of scripts and libraries, the most interesting one is called `dvitohtf`. It can either parse dvi file for the missing map (htf) files, or read list of fonts from the standard input. It then outputs TeX file, which then writes `htf` files when processed with plain TeX.

This is the TeX file created by this script for all fonts used in your document: [mylibertine.tex](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/88d4d4043313c322e14d99e8c6976e2c). I had to put it to a gist, because it is larger than Stackexchange allows in the posts.

Compile it using

```
tex mylibertine.tex
```

It should write all necessary HTF file.

Result:

[image]